# Regex - Split string by first ',

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to regex. I'm looking for an expression which will split a string after the first apostrophe. All strings start with an apostrophe.

So far I have:

```
(\'+$)
```

The following line should be split accordingly.

'I will never go away

{'}{I will never go away}

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using an application called Oracle EDQ.

Comment: Your regex says "look for one or more apostrophe characters in a row, up to the end of the line and remember it as a marked subexpression." Your example seems to say you want the apostrophe and the following characters split into two marked/captured subexpressions like ^(')(.*)$. I am not understanding the point of remembering the apostrophe that every line begins with, or what there is of value to remember (to split) before the apostrophe. Are you just dropping it? Why do you need to split on the first character of a line?

Comment: I'm fairly new to regex as I said. I have some data in which some lines begin with an apostrophe. I would like to remove them - and thought the easiest way was to split the string in two, and take the second part of the string. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `^'(.*)`, that is *anchor* the apostrophe to be the first of the line and match everything afterwards. However, if it is always the first character, why not use some substring functions, starting right after the beginning (usually at position `1`, if supported by your software, that is)?